# Serialize all class' fields to byte array

Tags: java

I have a Java class, like:

```
class Foo implements IBar
{
    // Methods ..

    // A bunch of fields of primitive types (int, String)
    int f1;
    int f2;
    String f3;
    // ...
}
```

I want to pack all these fields to the byte array (don't ask me why, this restriction is introduced by the C++ side that sends me data in such format).

The only way I found is to use `ByteBuffer`. But it is the worst I can thinks of. The code looks like:

```
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);

int offset = 0;

buf.putInt(f1);
System.arraycopy(buf.array(), 0, rawHeader, offset, 4);
offset += 4;

// A bunch of lines here (pack all other fields)
```

Does anyone know more suitable way of doing it? Thanks.

Comment: What order are your ints/floats packed?  If it's big-endian, the DataOutputStream answers will work.  If it's little-endian, ByteBuffer may be your best option because it is configurable.

Comment: why don;t you allocate one ByteBuffer for the entire result and just keep packing into that (instead of copying to a secondary array)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `DataOutputStream` wrapping a `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

Or, if you prefer, make your class implement `Serializable` and use an `ObjectOutputStream` wrapping a `ByteArrayOutputStream`. This will of course make a byte array readable only by Java.

Comment: Sorry, just noticed your post :)

Answer (score 2):

Mmm... You could try `DataOutputStream` over `ByteBufferStream`, it has convenient methods for writing primitives. As a payoff you have a byte array.

UPD: of course not `ByteBufferStream`, but `ByteArrayOutputStream`.